# How to draw a line that shows the border of QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to find draw a thick line around a `QGraphicsScene` in order to show the borders of it clearly but i could not find any function that does that for me. can you please tell me how i do this?

Comment: What do you mean the edges of QGraphicsScene, you could show a picture of what you want to get.

Comment: What do you mean by "around".  According to the docs "Items can be placed at any position on the scene, and the size of the scene is by default unlimited.".  But see the sceneRect and/or itemsBoundingRect methods... maybe those are what you're looking for.

Comment: check this http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html

Comment: Are you trying to draw a border for QGraphicsView?